# Given a ring $R$, when one talks of $R[X]$ what do they exactly mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given a ring $R$, when one talks of $R[X]$ what do they exactly mean?

To elaborate, do they mean ring of all elements of the form $a_nX^n + \ldots a_0$ where NO equivalences are present? I.e $a_nX^n + \ldots a_0 = b_m X^m + \ldots b_0$ iff $n=m$ and $a_i = b_i$ for all $i$?

Comment: Given a ring $R$, take $X$ not in $R$, then $R[X]$ is a new ring in which the operations are defined using the ones in $R$.

Comment: Usually when $X$ is used that is what is meant, with the "natural" addition and multiplication.

Comment: So consider $R[X]$ and let $S$ be the subring generated by $rX$, for some non invertible element $r \in R$. Then why is it that $X$ is not integral over $S$. As surely this would depend on $X$? If $X$ is nilpotent then trivially $X$ is integral over $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $R[X]$ denotes the polynomial ring. Two polynomials are equal iff their coefficients are equal (but you cannot conclude that $n=m$ in your formulation, you need $a_n,b_m \neq 0$).

There is a slight abuse of notation here: If $S$ is an $R$-algebra and $x \in S$, then $R[x]$ also denotes the image of $R[X] \to S, X \mapsto x$. This is why variables are often denoted by capital letters. In $R[x]$ we usually *have* relations between the powers of $x$. For example in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ we have $\sqrt{2}^2=2$ (but of course $X^2 \neq 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$).

Comment: So consider $R[x]$ and let $S$ be the subring generated by $rx$, for some non invertible element $r \in R$. Then why is it that $x$ is not integral over $S$. As surely this would depend on $x$? If $x$ is nilpotent then trivially $x$ is integral over $S$.

Comment: I.e When wanting to show that an element is integral over a ring, R, it would surely make no sense to talk about showing an arbitrary element is integral over $R$? We would have to be dealing with an element with some property?

Comment: Please ask this question in a separate question (and more understandable, in full sentences).

Comment: Sorry. I have added a new question.

Comment: Let us hope $R$ is commutative. Otherwise, what might $R[X]$ mean?